# ggbio::track function not recognizing coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to combine two separate boxplots using the `track` function of `ggbio`.
The graphs are on the y axis, so I need to flip the axis of the graphs and have been trying that using the `coord_flip` function.

The `coord_flip` function doesn't seem to work in this case, and I get two vertical side-by-side boxplots. Is there any other way to flip the axis or am I doing something wrong?

Data: I have a dataframe with a categorical variable, type, and quantitative value. Here is the code I am trying below to get two horizontal boxplots:

```
plot <- ggplot(new, aes(y=type, x=value)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()  
tracks(plot, plot)
```

Comment: `tracks` is part of the `ggbio` package (which is under bioconductor), not `ggplot2`

Comment: I can duplicate what you see with `p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() ; tracks(p, p)`. It does seem to be removing the `coord_flip`. Have you tried using `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` instead? i.e. `grid.arrange(p, p, ncol=1)`?

Comment: That does work, thanks! I was preferring something where the x-axis would be shared, though, rather than a gap between the two graphs.

Comment: there are some very hack-ish ways to do that but it means going down to the grob level. it seems `tracks` is not using `ggplot_build` and is not looking for the possible use of  `coord_flip`. You could try submitting a bug report to https://github.com/tengfei/ggbio/issues and see if the author is inclined to add support for `coord_flip`.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll do that, thx